# How to filter CSV File with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, grouping

I have a CSV file for the backup report in which I have multiple columns. I want to get only those clients who have never been successful with a particular save set.

Sample Input file is

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
a,All,Group1,Failed
a,SQL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group1,Failed
c,FS,Group1,Failed
d,DBA,Group1,Failed
e,RDM,Group1,Failed
a,ALL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group3,succeeded
c,SQL,Group4, Failed
```

Output

```
Client Name Save Set Name   Status  Group
a   All Failed  Group1
b   SQL Failed  Group1
c   FS  Failed  Group1
d   DBA Failed  Group1
e   RDM Failed  Group1
c   SQL Failed  Group4
```

Expected Output

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
c,FS,Group1,Failed
d,DBA,Group1,Failed
e,RDM,Group1,Failed
c,SQL,Group4, Failed
```

In my command below, the problem I am facing is that I am getting clients as `Failed` who gets successful in some other group whereas I want only those clients with save sets who got failed and don't have any success value in status.

```
Get-Content E:\Report\Daily_Failed.csv | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv | 
        Select-Object -Unique * | 
            Group-Object -Property 'Client Name', 'Save Set Name', 'Group' | 
                Where-Object { 0 -eq ($_.Group | Where-Object Status -eq 'succeeded').Count } | 
                    Select-Object -Expand Group | 
                        Select-Object "Client Name", "Save Set Name", "status", "Group" |
                            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation E:\Report\Failed_$CurrentDate.csv
```

Example 2.

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
gsiecwt2020.web.local,pseudo_saveset,D_CWT_File_System_1,failed
gsiecwt2020.web.local,J:\System,D_CWT_File_System_2,succeeded
gsiecwt2020.web.local,K:\System,D_CWT_File_System_1,succeeded
gsiecwt2020.web.local,K:\System,D_CWT_File_System_3,failed
```

Desired Output

```
gsiecwt2020.web.local,pseudo_saveset,D_CWT_File_System_1,failed
```

It should be matching `Client Name`, `Save Set Name` and `Status`.
If the client with same `Save Set Name` gets succeeded in any other group, then it should be marked as a success, but if the client with particular `Save Set Name` is failed then it should be marked as `Failed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter output (where-object) from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685989/filter-output-where-object-from-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `Group-Object` and a `Where-Object` clause.

For demo I'm using a Here-String; in real life you would import the csv from file with

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\yourInputFile.csv'
```

Code:

```
$csv = @"
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
a,All,Group1,Failed
a,SQL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group1,Failed
c,FS,Group1,Failed
d,DBA,Group1,Failed
e,RDM,Group1,Failed
a,ALL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group3,succeeded
c,SQL,Group4, Failed
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$result = $csv | Group-Object 'Client Name' | ForEach-Object {
    $succeeded = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'succeeded' }
    if (!$succeeded) { $_.Group }  # never succeeded, so output these
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\yourFilteredCsv.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
Client Name Save Set Name Group  Status
----------- ------------- -----  ------
c           FS            Group1 Failed
c           SQL           Group4 Failed
d           DBA           Group1 Failed
e           RDM           Group1 Failed
```

---

Seeing your latest comments, I think/hope I now understand the question better. Luckily, the code can be easily adjusted to group not only on 'Client Name', but also on 'Save Set Name' like below.

```
$result = $csv | Group-Object 'Client Name','Save Set Name' | ForEach-Object {
    # if any of the group items have a status of 'succeeded', skip that group
    $succeeded = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'succeeded' }
    if (!$succeeded) { $_.Group }  # never succeeded, so output these
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\yourFilteredCsv.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

**Using example 1:**

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
a,All,Group1,Failed
a,SQL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group1,Failed
c,FS,Group1,Failed
d,DBA,Group1,Failed
e,RDM,Group1,Failed
a,ALL,Group2,succeeded
b,SQL,Group3,succeeded
c,SQL,Group4, Failed
```

**yields:**

```
Client Name Save Set Name Group  Status
----------- ------------- -----  ------
c           FS            Group1 Failed
d           DBA           Group1 Failed
e           RDM           Group1 Failed
c           SQL           Group4 Failed
```

**Using example 2:**

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
gsiecwt2020.web.local,pseudo_saveset,D_CWT_File_System_1,failed
gsiecwt2020.web.local,J:\System,D_CWT_File_System_2,succeeded
gsiecwt2020.web.local,K:\System,D_CWT_File_System_1,succeeded
gsiecwt2020.web.local,K:\System,D_CWT_File_System_3,failed
```

**yields:**

```
Client Name           Save Set Name  Group               Status
-----------           -------------  -----               ------
gsiecwt2020.web.local pseudo_saveset D_CWT_File_System_1 failed
```

Comment: @Theo- Thanks for your effort. In your script, I am facing an issue that it's not taking the "save set" tab in consideration. If any of the save gets successful, it is marking complete Client as successful which should not be the case. I have updated my question with new example

Comment: @GURUSINGH I don't know what you mean.. The field `Save Set Name` is present in the output and no, it is not _marking the client successfull_. Your question is to find clients that have **never** been successfull, so in each group, I'm **testing** to see if there ever was any 'succeeded' status. Only if this is not the case, the client gets output because all Status fields for that client said 'Failed'. P.S. I don't see the question edited.

Comment: @Theo- Question updated with new Example and explanation. Please check

Comment: @Theo- Could you please help.?

Comment: @GURUSINGH I have added new code with example output. Hope I understood the question better this time.

Comment: This is what actually i was looking for. Thanks a lot.